# How do I set up a Rails "has_one :through" association with Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I come from a Rails background and am not really familiar with Doctrine. I am trying to set up a similar association to [this one in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association).

I have a `UserRelation` entity that contains a combination of `user_id` and `company_id` with a primary key. The same user can belong to multiple companies, and most data is stored with `user_relation_id`.

So, in this example I have a `Template` that has the following association set up which works fine:

```
/**
 * The UserRelation entity who created the template.
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserRelation")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_relation_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
protected $creator;
```

In this example I know I can just add a method to my template entity along the lines of:

```
public function getUser(): User
{
  return $this->creator->getUser();
}
```

but I need it to be filterable so that I can get all `Template` entities by `user_id` or `company_id` in a repository or controller like this:

```
$company = $entityManager->getRepository('Company')->find($company_id);
$templatesForCompany = $entityManager->getRepository('Template')->findBy('company' => $company);
```

Is there any way to set up this relationship so I can query it like above, instead of having to resort to raw SQL?